# delete cookies during page change , page close and page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i wanted to delete all my cookies in these events.Some says that by setting the cookie expire date to NULL or -1 will work.
i tried setting them and close the page and re-open the page again. but the cookie is still there.
i have checked the cookie status and it is shown session instead of expire date.

and cookies expired it will automatically delete from client side?or it is visible but unusable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.unload` event to delete cookies before the browser / page closes.

```
    $(window).unload(function() {
       $.cookies.del('name_of_your_cookie');
    });
```

Similarly you can use it with `.load` event.

Comment: i have alot of cookies and the names are dynamic. how can i loop through the cookies?can i use document.ready instead of .load?
by the way. i think is $.removeCookie('example');

Comment: What is the naming convention you've used for storing cookies? That'll be helpful to answer for how to loop through them.

Yes, you can use `document.ready`
And yes, both `$.cookies.del('example')` and `$.removeCookie('example');` will do the trick.

Comment: the naming are using $.cookie('left'+ controlID,value)

Comment: Simply use a for loop and iterate through various values of `controlID`

Comment: This is why every time I search for something JavaScript related my search query *must* include -jquery. Be a professional and stop using frameworks and libraries, browsers *already* support *real* JavaScript on the client *without* having people dump 70KB more bandwidth on a request.